# Using Universal Analytics events to track video duration with timestamp

Tags: javascript, vimeo, universal-analytics

I'm currently sending an analytics event each time a video is closed/stopped from a modal.  The videos are Vimeo and I'm using the API to watch the duration of the video on the time it is closed.

I'm using a Javascript date to differentiate each duration event.

```
var duration = 'vimeo play duration on stop';
var datelabel = new Date;

ga('send', 'event', 'Video Stop', 'Duration', datelabel, duration);
```

Is there a reason my `datelabel` is not showing up in the analytics dashboard?  Am I not allowed to timestamp each `duration` to break up each play separately in the reports?  If I were to use a fixed label, each duration value would be added together in the reports, which is what I DON'T want.

Thanks for reading and any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a few issues:

1. new Date returns an object, not a string. Try `var datelabel = new Date().toString();`.
2. You cannot pass in a string for event value. Event value [only accepts numbers](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events#overview).

Comment: Ahhhhh that's where I went wrong!  So I'll turn the date into a string.  As for the value, I am passing a number.  The example above is just placeholder, I should have been more clear on that.

Comment: I'll update my code and see if this works.  Will get back to you soon!